# C# - Programmatically change web.config file in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I am trying to created a program that changes and saves changes to a web.config file. The program is going to be for the first time setup of a web application. I did find a way to change the appSettings and connectionStrings, but anything else and I have been unsuccessful.

I want to be able to change the authentication mode between "Windows" and "Forms". The web.config file is setup like the following:

```
<system.web>
   <authentication mode="Windows">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Default.aspx" timeout="120"/>
   </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Also, want to be able to change the security mode between "Transport" and "None". The web.config for this section is like so:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAlarmNotifierCommunicationService" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I have tried going the same route as I did for changing the appSettings and connectionStrings to no avail. The following code does work to change those settings:

```
                System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/");
                ConnectionStringsSection section = config.GetSection("connectionStrings") as ConnectionStringsSection;

                if (section != null)
                {
                    section.ConnectionStrings["CustomerDB"].ConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source={0};User ID={1};PWD={2};Initial Catalog={3}", settings.SQLserverName, settings.SQLuserName, settings.SQLpassword, settings.SQLdatabaseName);
                    config.Save();
                }

                if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys.Contains("ApplicationUrl"))
                {
                    config.AppSettings.Settings["ApplicationUrl"].Value = string.Format("{0}://{1}/{2}/", settings.IsHttpsEnabled ? "https" : "http", settings.IsProteusMMXHostedSite ? "customerSite.com" : "localhost", settings.ApplicationName);
                    config.Save();
                }
```

I did try the following and I get an error for null reference when i tried this:

```
            var security = config.GetSection("system.serviceModel/bindings") as System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BindingsSection;

            if (security != null)
            {
                security.ElementInformation.Properties["mode"].Value = settings.IsHttpsEnabled ? "Transport" : "None";
                config.Save();
            }
```

I have spent a lot of time on this and am getting frustrated so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

[UPDATE] 
I am looking for something as easy as how I access and modify the appSettings and connectionStrings sections. I think I am close with the last bit of code in this post, where the variable is security. Without converting the web.config file to XML, there has to be a way to access and modify the web.config where i am talking about while using the Configuration class. I could be wrong, but it is very easy to do this with the appSettings and connectionStrings sections. Any guidance with this issue is much appreciated. Also, just to clarify, this is a one time setup of a web application before the first time the web application is run. I am trying to be able to configure each website put up within an UI, instead of having to modify the web.config directly. Thanks again.

Comment: We use config transforms for this during deployment. I'm not sure if the elements you want to modify can be changed at runtime. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Wouldn't your application restart everytime you changed the config? Anyway if you google the title of your question there are plenty on answers online. Basically you need to parse the xml file. See https://forums.asp.net/t/1355942.aspx